# Default Flutter icon shows in iOS when swiping up to show opened apps

Tags: ios, flutter, icons

I've replaced all my icon assets in my XCode runner project, both AppIcon, and LaunchImage.  However, the default flutter icon still appears when I swipe up in iOS to show the opened apps.  Is there another place that I need to look for where the default icon is being used?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`flutter_launcher_icons` plugin in combination of phone restart (cause icon was cached in phone) was fix for me.

Comment: Phone restart is what did it for me on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. 
I was running it in a simulator.

1. I erased the app
2. restarted the simulator
3. Ran the program again and it was fixed.

Comment: I saw this same problem with a physical device. Reinstalling the app showed the old icon. Probably cached and mapped to the app identifier. Restarting the device did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to properly format your app icon and make it propagate everywhere.

Copy paste your icon here: `assets/icon/icon.png`

Then in `pubspec.yaml` :

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon" 
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

Then in command line:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

And you're good to go

Comment: OK, I tried it, same result.  Icons are good everywhere except the one location...still default.

Comment: The solution is correct just the steps have a bit changed due to the plugin evolution => https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons